# Checking each character from text file , Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, file-handling

I have a text file, and when I read each line of the file and write it in array. I want to check if the character is not a dollar sign '$' . If it is, then Jump to next character and write the following part till the next dollar sign in next array. Therefore to divide each line in 3 parts, each part in different array.

Appreciate your time and help!

public void retrieveFromTxt() throws IOException

```
{
    textArea.setText(" ");
    String fileName = "Name_Of_City.txt";
    String line = " ";
    String entry = null;
    y = 0;

    char letter = '$', value = ' ';
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String TextLine = br.readLine();

    x = 1; // Random Variable to jump from character to character in array.
    // To Get Values Back from FIle Each value in correct array, I seperated each value with "$" sign 
    // Checking each letter and printing it to array[y] possition until the $ sign is met, then jump over it and continue in other array.
    try { 

        while(y < 19) {
            while(TextLine != null) {
                while(TextLine.charAt(x)!=(letter)) {
                    line = line +  TextLine.charAt(x);
                    Country[y] = ( line  );
                    x++;
                }
            }
            while(TextLine != null) {
                while(TextLine.charAt(x)!=(letter)) {
                    line = line +  TextLine.charAt(x);
                    City[y] = ( line  );
                    x++;
                }
            }
            while((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {
                while(line.charAt(x)!=(letter)) {
                    Population[y] = (textArea.getText()+ entry );

                    x++;
                }
            }
            y++;
            textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+ "\n" );
        }

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException error) {
        //Exception can be met if program cannot find the file , in that case messageDialog will pop up with help message
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Missing file"+",     " + fileName + ",     for a support contact oleninshelvijs@gmail.com!" ) ;
    }catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException err){}
    br1.close();
}
```

}

Comment: what have you tried so far ? if not you should look into the string tokenizer

Comment: Apparently you expect each line to have three parts, though this isn't clear because you gave us no sample input.  You might be able to get away with splitting on `$`.

Comment: @zython: Per folks who create and maintain Java, that's bad advice. Per the [StringTokenizer API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html): `"StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for the correction, the more your know

Answer (score 3):

Try using the string.split function.  You can do:

```
String s = "my$sign"
String parts[] = s.split("\\$")
```

Now parts[0] will hold "my" and parts[1] will hold "sign".

Edit: As pointed out by user Ukfub below, you will need to escape the symbol.  Updating my code to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

String parts[] = s.split("$")

That will not work because the parameter for the "split" method is a regular expression. You have to escape the special character '$':

```
String parts[] = s.split("\\$")
```